# Post in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an error when I try to use `POST` method through Retrofit 2 library. I want to ligon in vid.me service. This is the API of that service https://docs.vid.me/#api-Oauth-Authorize
but when I try to do this I have error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
                                                       for method VideoApi.getUserLogin
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:686)
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:704)
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:476)
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:328)
                                                       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:201)
                                                       at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                       at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                       at $Proxy1.getUserLogin(Native Method)
                                                       at com.example.vid_me_app.FeedFragment.Authorize(FeedFragment.java:48)
                                                       at com.example.vid_me_app.FeedFragment$1.onClick(FeedFragment.java:36)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**my API class:**

```
public interface VideoApi {

    @GET("/videos/featured")
    Call<Videos>getFeaturedVideo();
    @GET("/videos/new")
    Call<Videos>getNewVideo();
    @POST("oauth/authorize")
Call<SignInResult> getUserLogin(@Field("username")String username,@Field("password")String password,Callback<SignInResults> callback);
}
```

**my fragment:**

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button btnLogin;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_field);
        password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        btnLogin = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Authorize();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    public void Authorize(){
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);
       // Call<SignInResults> call = videoApi.getUserLogin(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(), new Callback<SignInResults>());
        videoApi.getUserLogin(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(), new Callback<SignInResults>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignInResults> call, Response<SignInResults> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.body().getSignInResults().get(0).getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignInResults> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation to the method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("oauth/authorize")
Call<SignInResult> getUserLogin(@Field("username")String username,@Field("password")String password,Callback<SignInResults> callback);
```

Comment: This is great solution, Finally found perfect solution After searching 2 hours

Comment: ok good thank to  Answer

i user 


    @POST(api.register)
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Object> getRegister(@Field("email") String email , @Field("password") String password , Callback<Object> callback  );
}